# what's the problem when integrating roxyfileman with tinymce in ABP

Tags: tinymce, abp

I want to use tinyMCE in ABP CoreMVC project,so I read the [http://www.iaspnetcore.com/Blog/BlogPost/5bd70fb5b169590f280f64dd/integrating-roxy-fileman-with-tinymce-in-aspnet-core], and add  RoxyFilemanController.cs 
in a normal netcore mvc project,and copy the tinymce and fileman directory to the www/lib directory,it works fine.but when I copy the same code to my ABP CoreMVC project,It not work. the controller code is:

```
 [Produces("application/json")]
public class RoxyFilemanController : Controller
{
    private string _systemRootPath;
    private string _tempPath;
    private string _filesRootPath;
    private string _filesRootVirtual;
    private Dictionary<string, string> _settings;
    private Dictionary<string, string> _lang = null;

    public RoxyFilemanController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Setup CMS paths to suit your environment (we usually inject settings for these)
        _systemRootPath = env.ContentRootPath;
        _tempPath = _systemRootPath + "\\wwwroot\\CMS\\Temp";
        _filesRootPath = "/wwwroot/CMS/Content";
        _filesRootVirtual = "/CMS/Content";
        // Load Fileman settings
        LoadSettings();
    }

    private void LoadSettings()
    {
        _settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(_systemRootPath + "/wwwroot/lib/fileman/conf.json"));
        string langFile = _systemRootPath + "/wwwroot/lib/fileman/lang/" + GetSetting("LANG") + ".json";
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(langFile)) langFile = _systemRootPath + "/wwwroot/lib/fileman/lang/en.json";
        _lang = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(langFile));
    }

    // GET api/RoxyFileman - test entry point//]
    [AllowAnonymous, Produces("text/plain"), ActionName("")]
    public string Get() { return "RoxyFileman - access to API requires Authorisation"; }

    #region API Actions
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult DIRLIST(string type)
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(GetFilesRoot());
            if (!d.Exists) throw new Exception("Invalid files root directory. Check your configuration.");
            ArrayList dirs = ListDirs(d.FullName);
            dirs.Insert(0, d.FullName);
            string localPath = _systemRootPath;
            string result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Count; i++)
            {
                string dir = (string)dirs[i];
                result += (result != "" ? "," : "") + "{\"p\":\"" + MakeVirtualPath(dir.Replace(localPath, "").Replace("\\", "/")) + "\",\"f\":\"" + GetFiles(dir, type).Count.ToString() + "\",\"d\":\"" + Directory.GetDirectories(dir).Length.ToString() + "\"}";
            }
            return Content("[" + result + "]", "application/json");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return Content(GetErrorRes(ex.Message)); }
    }

    public IActionResult FILESLIST(string d, string type)
    {
        try
        {
            d = MakePhysicalPath(d);
            CheckPath(d);
            string fullPath = FixPath(d);
            List<string> files = GetFiles(fullPath, type);
            string result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(files[i]);
                int w = 0, h = 0;
                // NO SUPPORT IN ASP.NET CORE! Per haps see https://github.com/CoreCompat/CoreCompat
                //if (GetFileType(f.Extension) == "image")
                //{
                //    try
                //    {
                //        //FileStream fs = new FileStream(f.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                //        //Image img = Image.FromStream(fs);
                //        //w = img.Width;
                //        //h = img.Height;
                //        //fs.Close();
                //        //fs.Dispose();
                //        //img.Dispose();
                //    }
                //    catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }
                //}
                result += (result != "" ? "," : "") +
                    "{" +
                    "\"p\":\"" + MakeVirtualPath(d) + "/" + f.Name + "\"" +
                    ",\"t\":\"" + Math.Ceiling(LinuxTimestamp(f.LastWriteTime)).ToString() + "\"" +
                    ",\"s\":\"" + f.Length.ToString() + "\"" +
                    ",\"w\":\"" + w.ToString() + "\"" +
                    ",\"h\":\"" + h.ToString() + "\"" +
                    "}";
            }
            return Content("[" + result + "]");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return Content(GetErrorRes(ex.Message)); }
    }

    public IActionResult COPYDIR(string d, string n)
    {
        try
        {
            d = MakePhysicalPath(d);
            n = MakePhysicalPath(n);
            CheckPath(d);
            CheckPath(n);
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(FixPath(d));
            DirectoryInfo newDir = new DirectoryInfo(FixPath(n + "/" + dir.Name));
            if (!dir.Exists) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_CopyDirInvalidPath"));
            else if (newDir.Exists) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_DirAlreadyExists"));
            else CopyDir(dir.FullName, newDir.FullName);
            return Content(GetSuccessRes());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return Content(GetErrorRes(ex.Message)); }
    }

    public IActionResult COPYFILE(string f, string n)
    {
        try
        {
            f = MakePhysicalPath(f);
            CheckPath(f);
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(FixPath(f));
            n = FixPath(n);
            if (!file.Exists) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_CopyFileInvalisPath"));
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    System.IO.File.Copy(file.FullName, Path.Combine(n, MakeUniqueFilename(n, file.Name)));
                    return Content(GetSuccessRes());
                }
                catch (Exception) { throw new Exception(LangRes("E_CopyFile")); }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return Content(GetErrorRes(ex.Message)); }
    }

    public IActionResult CREATEDIR(string d, string n)
    {
        try
        {
            d = MakePhysicalPath(d);
            CheckPath(d);
            d = FixPath(d);
            if (!Directory.Exists(d)) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_CreateDirInvalidPath"));
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    d = Path.Combine(d, n);
                    if (!Directory.Exists(d)) Directory.CreateDirectory(d);
                    return Content(GetSuccessRes());
                }
                catch (Exception) { throw new Exception(LangRes("E_CreateDirFailed")); }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return Content(GetErrorRes(ex.Message)); }
    }

    public IActionResult DELETEDIR(string d)
    {
        try
        {
            d = MakePhysicalPath(d);
            CheckPath(d);
            d = FixPath(d);
            if (!Directory.Exists(d)) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_DeleteDirInvalidPath"));
            else if (d == GetFilesRoot()) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_CannotDeleteRoot"));
            else if (Directory.GetDirectories(d).Length > 0 || Directory.GetFiles(d).Length > 0) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_DeleteNonEmpty"));
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Directory.Delete(d);
                    return Content(GetSuccessRes());
                }
                catch (Exception) { throw new Exception(LangRes("E_CannotDeleteDir")); }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return Content(GetErrorRes(ex.Message)); }
    }

    public IActionResult DELETEFILE(string f)
    {
        try
        {
            f = MakePhysicalPath(f);
            CheckPath(f);
            f = FixPath(f);
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(f)) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_DeleteFileInvalidPath"));
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(f);
                    return Content(GetSuccessRes());
                }
                catch (Exception) { throw new Exception(LangRes("E_DeletеFile")); }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return Content(GetErrorRes(ex.Message)); }
    }

    public ActionResult DOWNLOAD(string f)
    {
        try
        {
            f = MakePhysicalPath(f);
            CheckPath(f);
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(FixPath(f));
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                string contentType;
                new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(file.FullName, out contentType);
                return PhysicalFile(file.FullName, contentType ?? "application/octet-stream", file.Name);
            }
            else return NotFound();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return Json(GetErrorRes(ex.Message)); }
    }

    public ActionResult DOWNLOADDIR(string d)
    {
        try
        {
            d = MakePhysicalPath(d);
            d = FixPath(d);
            if (!Directory.Exists(d)) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_CreateArchive"));
            string dirName = new FileInfo(d).Name;
            string tmpZip = _tempPath + "/" + dirName + ".zip";
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(tmpZip)) System.IO.File.Delete(tmpZip);
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(d, tmpZip, CompressionLevel.Fastest, true);
            return PhysicalFile(tmpZip, "application/zip", dirName + ".zip");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return Json(GetErrorRes(ex.Message)); }
    }

    public IActionResult MOVEDIR(string d, string n)
    {
        try
        {
            d = MakePhysicalPath(d);
            n = MakePhysicalPath(n);
            CheckPath(d);
            CheckPath(n);
            DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(FixPath(d));
            DirectoryInfo dest = new DirectoryInfo(FixPath(Path.Combine(n, source.Name)));
            if (dest.FullName.IndexOf(source.FullName) == 0) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_CannotMoveDirToChild"));
            else if (!source.Exists) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_MoveDirInvalisPath"));
            else if (dest.Exists) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_DirAlreadyExists"));
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    source.MoveTo(dest.FullName);
                    return Content(GetSuccessRes());
                }
                catch (Exception) { throw new Exception(LangRes("E_MoveDir") + " \"" + d + "\""); }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return Content(GetErrorRes(ex.Message)); }
    }

    public IActionResult MOVEFILE(string f, string n)
    {
        try
        {
            f = MakePhysicalPath(f);
            n = MakePhysicalPath(n);
            CheckPath(f);
            CheckPath(n);
            FileInfo source = new FileInfo(FixPath(f));
            FileInfo dest = new FileInfo(FixPath(n));
            if (!source.Exists) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_MoveFileInvalisPath"));
            else if (dest.Exists) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_MoveFileAlreadyExists"));
            else if (!CanHandleFile(dest.Name)) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_FileExtensionForbidden"));
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    source.MoveTo(dest.FullName);
                    return Content(GetSuccessRes());
                }
                catch (Exception) { throw new Exception(LangRes("E_MoveFile") + " \"" + f + "\""); }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return Content(GetErrorRes(ex.Message)); }
    }

    public IActionResult RENAMEDIR(string d, string n)
    {
        try
        {
            d = MakePhysicalPath(d);
            CheckPath(d);
            DirectoryInfo source = new DirectoryInfo(FixPath(d));
            DirectoryInfo dest = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(source.Parent.FullName, n));
            if (source.FullName == GetFilesRoot()) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_CannotRenameRoot"));
            else if (!source.Exists) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_RenameDirInvalidPath"));
            else if (dest.Exists) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_DirAlreadyExists"));
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    source.MoveTo(dest.FullName);
                    return Content(GetSuccessRes());
                }
                catch (Exception) { throw new Exception(LangRes("E_RenameDir") + " \"" + d + "\""); }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return Content(GetErrorRes(ex.Message)); }
    }

    public IActionResult RENAMEFILE(string f, string n)
    {
        try
        {
            f = MakePhysicalPath(f);
            CheckPath(f);
            FileInfo source = new FileInfo(FixPath(f));
            FileInfo dest = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(source.Directory.FullName, n));
            if (!source.Exists) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_RenameFileInvalidPath"));
            else if (!CanHandleFile(n)) throw new Exception(LangRes("E_FileExtensionForbidden"));
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    source.MoveTo(dest.FullName);
                    return Content(GetSuccessRes());
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { throw new Exception(ex.Message + "; " + LangRes("E_RenameFile") + " \"" + f + "\""); }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return Content(GetErrorRes(ex.Message)); }
    }

    [HttpPost, Produces("text/plain")]
    public string UPLOAD(string d)
    {
        try
        {
            d = MakePhysicalPath(d);
            CheckPath(d);
            d = FixPath(d);
            string res = GetSuccessRes();
            bool hasErrors = false;
            try
            {
                foreach (var file in HttpContext.Request.Form.Files)
                {
                    if (CanHandleFile(file.FileName))
                    {
                        FileInfo f = new FileInfo(file.FileName);
                        string filename = MakeUniqueFilename(d, f.Name);
                        string dest = Path.Combine(d, filename);
                        using (var saveFile = new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create)) file.CopyTo(saveFile);
                        //if (GetFileType(new FileInfo(filename).Extension) == "image")
                        //{
                        //    int w = 0;
                        //    int h = 0;
                        //    int.TryParse(GetSetting("MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH"), out w);
                        //    int.TryParse(GetSetting("MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT"), out h);
                        //    ImageResize(dest, dest, w, h);
                        //}
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hasErrors = true;
                        res = GetSuccessRes(LangRes("E_UploadNotAll"));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { res = GetErrorRes(ex.Message); }
            if (IsAjaxUpload())
            {
                if (hasErrors) res = GetErrorRes(LangRes("E_UploadNotAll"));
                return res;
            }
            else return "<script>parent.fileUploaded(" + res + ");</script>";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (!IsAjaxUpload()) return "<script>parent.fileUploaded(" + GetErrorRes(LangRes("E_UploadNoFiles")) + ");</script>";
            else return GetErrorRes(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    /*
    public string GENERATETHUMB(string type)
    {
        try
        {
            //int w = 140, h = 0;
            //int.TryParse(_context.Request["width"].Replace("px", ""), out w);
            //int.TryParse(_context.Request["height"].Replace("px", ""), out h);
            //ShowThumbnail(_context.Request["f"], w, h);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { return GetErrorRes(ex.Message); }
    }
    */
    #endregion

    #region Utilities
    private string MakeVirtualPath(string path)
    {
        return !path.StartsWith(_filesRootPath) ? path : _filesRootVirtual + path.Substring(_filesRootPath.Length);
    }

    private string MakePhysicalPath(string path)
    {
        return !path.StartsWith(_filesRootVirtual) ? path : _filesRootPath + path.Substring(_filesRootVirtual.Length);
    }

    private string GetFilesRoot()
    {
        string ret = _filesRootPath;
        if (GetSetting("SESSION_PATH_KEY") != "" && HttpContext.Session.GetString(GetSetting("SESSION_PATH_KEY")) != null) ret = HttpContext.Session.GetString(GetSetting("SESSION_PATH_KEY"));
        ret = FixPath(ret);
        return ret;
    }

    private ArrayList ListDirs(string path)
    {
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        ArrayList ret = new ArrayList();
        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            ret.Add(dir);
            ret.AddRange(ListDirs(dir));
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private List<string> GetFiles(string path, string type)
    {
        List<string> ret = new List<string>();
        if (type == "#" || type == null) type = "";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        foreach (string f in files) { if ((GetFileType(new FileInfo(f).Extension) == type) || (type == "")) ret.Add(f); }
        return ret;
    }

    private string GetFileType(string ext)
    {
        string ret = "file";
        ext = ext.ToLower();
        if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".png" || ext == ".gif") ret = "image";
        else if (ext == ".swf" || ext == ".flv") ret = "flash";
        return ret;
    }

    private void CheckPath(string path)
    {
        if (FixPath(path).IndexOf(GetFilesRoot()) != 0) throw new Exception("Access to " + path + " is denied");
    }

    private string FixPath(string path)
    {
        path = path.TrimStart('~');
        if (!path.StartsWith("/")) path = "/" + path;
        return _systemRootPath + path;
    }

    private double LinuxTimestamp(DateTime d)
    {
        DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime();
        TimeSpan timeSpan = (d.ToLocalTime() - epoch);
        return timeSpan.TotalSeconds;
    }

    private string GetSetting(string name)
    {
        string ret = "";
        if (_settings.ContainsKey(name)) ret = _settings[name];
        return ret;
    }

    private string GetErrorRes(string msg) { return GetResultStr("error", msg); }

    private string GetResultStr(string type, string msg)
    {
        return "{\"res\":\"" + type + "\",\"msg\":\"" + msg.Replace("\"", "\\\"") + "\"}";
    }

    private string LangRes(string name) { return _lang.ContainsKey(name) ? _lang[name] : name; }

    private string GetSuccessRes(string msg) { return GetResultStr("ok", msg); }

    private string GetSuccessRes() { return GetSuccessRes(""); }

    private void CopyDir(string path, string dest)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(dest)) Directory.CreateDirectory(dest);
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(path))
        {
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(f);
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(dest, file.Name))) System.IO.File.Copy(f, Path.Combine(dest, file.Name));
        }
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(path)) CopyDir(d, Path.Combine(dest, new DirectoryInfo(d).Name));
    }

    private string MakeUniqueFilename(string dir, string filename)
    {
        string ret = filename;
        int i = 0;
        while (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(dir, ret)))
        {
            i++;
            ret = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename) + " - Copy " + i.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(filename);
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private bool CanHandleFile(string filename)
    {
        bool ret = false;
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filename);
        string ext = file.Extension.Replace(".", "").ToLower();
        string setting = GetSetting("FORBIDDEN_UPLOADS").Trim().ToLower();
        if (setting != "")
        {
            ArrayList tmp = new ArrayList();
            tmp.AddRange(Regex.Split(setting, "\\s+"));
            if (!tmp.Contains(ext)) ret = true;
        }
        setting = GetSetting("ALLOWED_UPLOADS").Trim().ToLower();
        if (setting != "")
        {
            ArrayList tmp = new ArrayList();
            tmp.AddRange(Regex.Split(setting, "\\s+"));
            if (!tmp.Contains(ext)) ret = false;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private bool IsAjaxUpload()
    {
        return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Request.Query["method"]) && HttpContext.Request.Query["method"].ToString() == "ajax");
    }
    #endregion

    /*
        public bool ThumbnailCallback()
        {
            return false;
        }

        protected void ShowThumbnail(string path, int width, int height)
        {
            CheckPath(path);
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(FixPath(path), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromStream(fs));
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
            int cropWidth = img.Width, cropHeight = img.Height;
            int cropX = 0, cropY = 0;

            double imgRatio = (double)img.Width / (double)img.Height;

            if(height == 0)
                height = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)width / imgRatio));

            if (width > img.Width)
                width = img.Width;
            if (height > img.Height)
                height = img.Height;

            double cropRatio = (double)width / (double)height;
            cropWidth = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)img.Height * cropRatio));
            cropHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)cropWidth / cropRatio));
            if (cropWidth > img.Width)
            {
                cropWidth = img.Width;
                cropHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)cropWidth / cropRatio));
            }
            if (cropHeight > img.Height)
            {
                cropHeight = img.Height;
                cropWidth = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)cropHeight * cropRatio));
            }
            if(cropWidth < img.Width){
                cropX = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)(img.Width - cropWidth) / 2));
            }
            if(cropHeight < img.Height){
                cropY = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((double)(img.Height - cropHeight) / 2));
            }

            Rectangle area = new Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight);
            Bitmap cropImg = img.Clone(area, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
            img.Dispose();
            Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort imgCallback = new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);

            _r.AddHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
            cropImg.GetThumbnailImage(width, height, imgCallback, IntPtr.Zero).Save(_r.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            _r.OutputStream.Close();
            cropImg.Dispose();
        }

        private ImageFormat GetImageFormat(string filename){
            ImageFormat ret = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
            switch(new FileInfo(filename).Extension.ToLower()){
                case ".png": ret = ImageFormat.Png; break;
                case ".gif": ret = ImageFormat.Gif; break;
            }
            return ret;
        }

        protected void ImageResize(string path, string dest, int width, int height)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            Image img = Image.FromStream(fs);
            fs.Close();
            fs.Dispose();
            float ratio = (float)img.Width / (float)img.Height;
            if ((img.Width <= width && img.Height <= height) || (width == 0 && height == 0))
                return;

            int newWidth = width;
            int newHeight = Convert.ToInt16(Math.Floor((float)newWidth / ratio));
            if ((height > 0 && newHeight > height) || (width == 0))
            {
                newHeight = height;
                newWidth = Convert.ToInt16(Math.Floor((float)newHeight * ratio));
            }
            Bitmap newImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)newImg);
            g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            img.Dispose();
            g.Dispose();
            if(dest != ""){
                newImg.Save(dest, GetImageFormat(dest));
            }
            newImg.Dispose();
        }

        public bool IsReusable {
            get {
                return false;
            }
        }
    */
}
```

In ABP CoreMVC,I change the About/index.html as follow:

```html
@using testRoxyMan.Web.Startup
   
<script src="~/lib/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RoxyFileBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {
        var roxyFileman = '/lib/fileman/index.html';
        if (roxyFileman.indexOf("?") < 0) {
            roxyFileman += "?type=" + type;
        }
        else {
            roxyFileman += "&type=" + type;
        }
        roxyFileman += '&input=' + field_name + '&value=' + win.document.getElementById(field_name).value;
        if (tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.language) {
            roxyFileman += '&langCode=' + tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.language;
        }
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
            file: roxyFileman,
            title: 'Roxy Fileman',
            width: 850,
            height: 650,
            resizable: "yes",
            plugins: "media",
            inline: "yes",
            close_previous: "no"
        }, { window: win, input: field_name });
        return false;
    }

    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
        theme: 'modern',
        height: 200,
        width: '100%',
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink autoresize directionality lists link image charmap preview anchor",
            "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen textcolor",
            "insertdatetime media table contextmenu "
        ],
        toolbar: 'ltr rtl | insertfile undo redo | styleselect | fontselect | fontsizeselect | bold italic | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
        file_browser_callback: RoxyFileBrowser
       
    });
</script>

<div class="row clearfix">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

but when I click the addImg btn,It not work,
the wrong msg is:
    An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ComponentNotFoundException: No component for supporting the service testRoxyMan.Web.Mvc.Controllers.RoxyFilemanController was found

Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy, bool ignoreParentContext)

so ,what's problem? Thanks a lot

Comment: the orginal wrong msg is: E_LoadingAjax /RoxyFileman/DIRLIST

Answer (score 0):

Try to inherit **AbpController**

```
public class RoxyFilemanController : AbpController
```

Comment: thank you,I tried,but  still the the same wrong msg show

Comment: Please follow: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/4530